# Getting computed column filled in EF Core on every call to entity

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, calculated-columns

I am using code first with Entity Framework in my ASP.NET Core application. I am using a generic repository for crud operations.

I have a base audit class which is inherited by all entities in my dbcontext.

```
public class Audit_base
{
        public int AddedUserId { get; set; }
        public int ModifiedUserId { get; set; }

        // I'd like to have it filled every time I query 
        [NotMapped] 
        public String AddedUsername { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public String EditedUserName { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a `User` class in the dbcontext

```
public class UserMaster 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }       
    public int FullName { get; set; }
}
```

All my tables (about 70) inherit from the `Audit_base` class.

```
public class Book : Audit_base
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String BookName { get; set; }
    public virtual UserMaster CreatedByUser { get; set; }
    public virtual UserMaster ModifiedByUser { get; set; }       
}
```

And this is the part of generic repository class where I query these tables

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly ApplicationContext _context;

    public GenericRepository(ApplicationContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    } 

    public IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        return _context.Set<T>().Where(expression);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.Set<T>().ToList();
    }

    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return _context.Set<T>().Find(id);
    }    
}
```

Is there a way that I can get the user name corresponding to the created and modified userid when I query it, like a computed column?

Comment: Why these fields are `NotMapped` ?

Comment: because I dont want them in database